# Display is monochrone - Using Mantic Minotaur in both Wayland and X11

Tags: display, 23.10

I am using Mantic Minotaur and the display is completely desaturated. Please help me return the display to what it was under previous versions with normal level of color.

[image]

Comment: SO I have provided a description of the problem, if no body wants to help, fine.

Comment: You'll have to explain what you did. No one can just look at an end state and tell you how you got there.