# I am running Mantic Minotaur. The display is completely desaturated. Please help me return the display to a normal set of colors

Tags: xorg, display, wayland

My display running Ubuntu Studio Mantic Minotaur (23.10) is completely de saturated. Can anyone point me to a reason why this would be happening?

[image: desaturated desktop]

I am a little disappointed that my previous post was downvoted without any specific reason given. If there is any file that I should publish or information submitted I can do that, but please stop downvoting this. I have not really gotten into configuration files in quite a while, I used to do that with OpenSUSE and received much help back then when I used to use that distro, but I have moved to Ubuntu Studio and was looking forward to a similar level of help.

Comment: Please post a question only once. [Display is monochrone - Using Mantic Minotaur in both Wayland and X11](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1508406/display-is-monochrone-using-mantic-minotaur-in-both-wayland-and-x11) It's bad enough to start using a site and complain about it; it's worse to break the rules while doing it. Your previous post contained zero details to let anyone troubleshoot your issue.